# Solution for offloading user-uploaded files to an external site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a site I'm working on, I want users to be able to upload songs that others can listen to. The Rails application will be hosted on a Linode VPS, but I'd like to host the actual songs files somewhere other than the VPS, possibly a Dreamhost or Amazon S3 account.

What do you guys think a good solution for this would be?
Allow the users to upload to the VPS, then have the VPS ftp or otherwise transfer the file to the external hosting service in the background, and notify the user when it is complete? Or some other crazy, cool solution?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I built a sample project which uploads to Amazon S3 and bypasses your Rails server entirely.  I would recommend using that kind of solution so you don't tie up your Rails server process with the upload.

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash/Silverlight/GoogleGears/BrowserPlus and jQuery-based Plupload to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload

Comment: This is very cool and will likely be helpful, but I'm still hoping for other solutions. At least to start with, it'll be much cheaper for me to host files on Dreamhost. If the site grows to the point I hope it does, then I'll definitely move to S3 or another cloud-platform for file hosting; but for now, I'm hoping for a solution where the file host service isn't S3, but something with an interface I control on that end (ftp, a php solution of some sort, etc).

Comment: Keep in mind that you can use CyberDuck FTP client to "ftp" into Amazon S3 and manipulate files just like any other FTP host.  Best of luck to you